# Creating a read-only repository with SpringData

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to create read-only repositories using Spring Data?

I have some entities linked to views and some child entities for which I would like to provide a repository with some methods like `findAll()`, `findOne()` and some methods with the `@Query`annotation. I would like to avoid providing methods like `save(…)` and `delete(…)` since they make no sense and could create errors.

```
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<ContactModel, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ContactModel> {
    List<ContactModel> findContactByAddress_CityModel_Id(Integer cityId);

    List<ContactModel> findContactByAddress_CityModel_Region_Id(Integer regionId);

    // ... methods using @Query

    // no need to save/flush/delete
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, the way to go is to add a handcrafted base repository. You usually use something like this:

```
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

  T findOne(ID id);

  Iterable<T> findAll();
}
```

You can now have you concrete repos extend that just defined one:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<Person, Long> {

  T findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

The crucial part defining the base repo is that the method declarations carry the *very same signature* as the methods declared in `CrudRepository` if that's the case we can still route the calls into the implementation bean backing the repository proxy. I've written a more detailed [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/07/27/fine-tuning-spring-data-repositories/) about that topic in the SpringSource blog.

Comment: There is one tricky thing. If I am using an in-memory database like HSQL for integration testing, I can use the save method of the view to create test data instead of creating a relation between its objects and populating them. So in this case I will need the view's save method only for testing but not for production code. Is there a way to achieve it ?

Comment: Note that from 2.0 M3 (Kay) version in the onwards findOne method has been renamed to findById, details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101061/missing-crudrepositoryfindone-method

Comment: Suppose you still want Spring to create implementations of some `PagingAndSortingRepository` methods but not all of them. How would you then go about creating a `PagingAndSortingReadOnlyRepository` that has the same interface minus the save and delete methods?

Comment: This solution throws `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type CustomEntity!` exception for newer versions. Use `findById` instead.

Comment: For extra efficiency, you can mark the repository transaction as read only by adding `@Transactional(readonly=true)` to the interface: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Answer (score 37):

To expand on Oliver Gierke's answer, in the more recent versions of Spring Data you will need the @NoRepositoryBean annotation on your ReadOnlyRepository (parent interface) to prevent application start up errors:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    T findOne(ID id);

    List<T> findAll();

}
```

Comment: The findOne method is no longer necessary.

Comment: Getting `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type` Error while starting up. When remove `T findOne(ID id);`, it works fine, but cannot view single item via URL.

Comment: maybe because it's not called `findById` as explained in a comment above... also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101061/missing-crudrepositoryfindone-method ???

Answer (score 7):

As far as we can see in documentation, this is possible by implementing [org.springframework.data.repository.Repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html).

Answer (score 6):

For me the following worked. Using Oliver's solution, I was getting error `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type` while starting up.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T,ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    Optional<T> findById(ID var1);
    boolean existsById(ID var1);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> var1);
    long count();
}
```

Comment: that's because there has been a renaming of several methods; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101061/missing-crudrepositoryfindone-method

Comment: This is the valid solution for latest spring version

Answer (score 5):

This is for read-only [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)

```
package com.oracle.odc.data.catalog.service.core.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

/**
 * Extension of {@link PagingAndSortingRepository} but without modification capabilities
 *
 * @author XYZ
 * @see Sort
 * @see Pageable
 * @see Page
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyPagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    void deleteById(ID id);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    void delete(T entity);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    void deleteAll();

}
```

If you try to POST or DELETE, you will get 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: this prevents from being executed at runtime, but not from being used by developers at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to make your own implementation or block this actions - you can do something like this (works withJava 8 and higher):

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import java.util.List;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    default <S extends T> S save(@NonNull S entity) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed");
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    default <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(@NonNull Iterable<S> iterable) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    default <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(@NonNull S s) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void delete(@NonNull T entity) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteAll() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteAll(@NonNull Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteAllInBatch() {
       throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteById(@NonNull ID id) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }

    @Override
    default void deleteInBatch(@NonNull Iterable<T> iterable) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Action not allowed.");
    }
}
```

Hope I help somebody (ノ^∇^)