# Spring data rest - Is there a global switch to block all delete operations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am currently using `@RestResource(exported = false)` on all delete operations in a repository to hide delete requests. This is done explicitly in repositories extending JPA repository.

Is there a global switch to block all delete operations?

Comment: You could have `interface ModelRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> { @RestResource(exported = false) void delete(ID id); @RestResource(exported = false) void delete(T entity); @RestResource(exported = false) void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities); @RestRespource(exported = false) void deleteAll(); }` and then `interface MyRepository extends ModelRepository<Entity, Long>`.

Comment: You can create a read-only repository, as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107136/creating-a-read-only-repository-with-springdata

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to annotate all your delete operations with `@RestResource(exported = false)`.

- Spring data doc: [Hiding Repository CRUD methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repository-crud-methods)

Example from Spring data doc:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "people", rel = "people")
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

@Override
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  void delete(Long id);

  @Override
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  void delete(Person entity);
}
```

Explanation below:

> If you want turn them off, then just keep in mind you have to annotate both
>   versions with exported = false.

So by default, if there is not new you need to annotate all your operations. But if you are very interested at the moment you could perform your own annotation with a implementation which does it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have another follow-up question. Does DELETE request on the association item calls this delete operation internally ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. So if I understand it: `void delete(Person entity)` internally calls `void delete(ID id)` how? it extracts the ID from `entity` and then calls `void delete(ID id)`  as next `delete(entityInformation.getId(entity));`

Comment: Delete on /{repository}/{id}/{property} internally calls findOne(id) -> BeforeLinkDeleteEvent -> Save() -> AfterLinkDeleteEvent. How to block such  a request ?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, there is now the [ability to only expose repository methods explicitly declared for exposure](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1176)

See [RepositoryRestConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/a10aa934b794bffb7bfbbac22e7bfc72ea4fdcc8/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java)

Comment: If this is of interest to you, consider also upvoting this ticket 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1034