# Error Run Spring Boot (Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, compiler-errors

I'm watching a class and I did everything exactly like a class and it's making a mistake in compiling.
Follows Code and Class

> 2019-10-16 22:49:39.528  INFO 7668 --- [           main]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-10-16 22:49:39.544
>   ERROR 7668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'pessoaController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImp': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'pessoaRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed
>   to create query for method public abstract com.mydream.mydream.Pessoa
>   com.mydream.mydream.PessoaRepository.findOne(java.lang.Long)! No
>   property findOne found for type Pessoa!   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)

Pessoa.java

```
package com.mydream.mydream;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="PESSOA")
public class Pessoa {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String apelido;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(final String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getApelido() {
        return apelido;
    }

    public void setApelido(String apelido) {
        this.apelido = apelido;
    }

}
```

PessoaService.java

```
package com.mydream.mydream;

import java.util.List;

public interface PessoaService {
    List<Pessoa>listar();

    Pessoa listarId(Long id);

    Pessoa add(Pessoa p);
    Pessoa edit(Pessoa p);
    Pessoa delete(Long id);
}
```

PessoaServiceImp.java

```
package com.mydream.mydream;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PessoaServiceImp implements PessoaService {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Pessoa> listar() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Pessoa listarId(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pessoa add(Pessoa p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pessoa edit(Pessoa p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Pessoa delete(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

PessoaRepository.java

```
package com.mydream.mydream;

import com.mydream.mydream.Pessoa;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface PessoaRepository extends Repository<Pessoa, Long>{
    List<Pessoa> findAll();

    Pessoa findOne(Long id);
    Pessoa save(Pessoa p);
    void delete(Pessoa p);

}
```

PessoaController.java

```
package com.mydream.mydream;

import com.mydream.mydream.Pessoa;
import com.mydream.mydream.PessoaService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path= "/pessoas")
public class PessoaController {

    @Autowired
    PessoaService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Pessoa>listar(){
        return service.listar();
    }
}
```

I already did what I had in other posts but I got no solution

Comment: As you can see in the [link to duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103020/5221149) (above the question), rename method to `findById` and change return type to `Optional<Pessoa>`. --- Or use an older version of Spring Data (<2.0)

Answer (score 1):

@Repository annotation is missing in PessoaService

Comment: In _PessoaService_? Error is present

Thank you for your help!