# Spring Boot - Allow only read operations on JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to allow only reading operations on my JpaRepository.

I found a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107136/creating-a-read-only-repository-with-springdata/37297495) but it seems to tackle only the case of a simple Repository:

```
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

  T findOne(ID id);

  Iterable<T> findAll();
}
```

What I need instead, is to apply the same but for my JpaRepository or PagingAndSortingRepository.

The reason is I want my read-only repo to support **Paging**.

So, how I can make a read/write-only JpaRepository or PagingAndSortingRepository?

(using Spring Boot 2.3.1)

Comment: To support paging why need to make repo read only ?

Comment: Because I want to have two datasources one for reading and one for writing, and for reading I would like have paging support.

Comment: Are you talking about the whole Repository, e.g., as used in code, or about which REST endpoints get exposed using Spring Data Rest? Your question is only tagged with "spring-data-jpa", but the link points to a spd REST issue.

Comment: No I am talking about the Repository itself.